# how to format a external HDD in Fat32 to swap between Ubuntu and Windows 7

Tags: 12.10, windows-7, hard-drive, macosx, fat32

Have a 750 gig external HDD. Have format it in Ubuntu 12.10 using FAT32 since I have to switch between windows, linux and osX. Used quick format option when doing this. Have named drive but Ubuntu doesn't give drive letter. Tried loading on windows 7 and drive comes up under manager as unallocated. Any suggestions about how what I did wrong and how to fix this problem? Thanks.

JH

Comment: I'm not sure about OSX, but Linux have no trouble accessing NTFS partitions - no reason to use FAT which is kinda not terribly reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Linux (and thus Ubuntu) does not use drive letters. Look on your desktop or in the /media folder

If that doesn't help, read up on linux "mounting" and USB especially ([Ubtunu Mount/USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB) page is as good a place to start as any)

Comment: Hi, the drive mounts no problem on linux systems and Mac OSX, just not on Windows 7.

Comment: Then this is not an ubuntu question. You should probably assign the drive a drive letter: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/change-drive-letters-windows-7.htm

Comment: I would do this if I could but this option doesn't come up under computer management. When I go there the drive is listed as unallocated and there isn't the option to assign a letter, just reformat.

Comment: make sure you formatted as FAT, give the output of mount